# WordPress: save API JSON after publish a post

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to grab all my blog posts and save then in a json file using the exactly structure provided by WordPress API Rest after a post is published. So I'm using this:

```
add_action('publish_post', function($ID, $post) {
    $url = 'http://website.local/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/';
    $response = wp_remote_get( $url );
    file_put_contents('data.json', $response);
}, 10, 2);
```

But it's returning an error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class
>   Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary could not be converted to
>   string in
>   /var/www/public/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/functions.php on
>   line 578

Comment: before the call to file_put_contents, can you do a print_r($response) and see what the output is? It looks like $response is an object and it doesnt know how to interpret it as a string

Comment: $response = wp_remote_get( $url ); than do jsondecode and set second parameter true json_decode($response,true);

Comment: @Aki actually, I need to run json_encode. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I think: json_encode($response-> **getAll** ()). Otherwise you'll have a useless `{"data": ....}` around your JSON.

Comment: @marcelo2605 does my answer is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you need to use json encode function to convert the return to string:

```
$response = wp_remote_get( $url );
$responseData = json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Why do you use true? It resolves to `JSON_HEX_TAG ` with `json_encode`.