# How would I create a .json file of my local Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, debugging

I've looked online but can't seem to find a concrete way of doing this.  I've also searched up plugins that I can use but not sure which ones would be a viable option.  What's the simplest way of doing this?

Comment: Please explain why you need to do this and we might be able to offer some actual useful suggestions. Without some more context all we can do is guess.

Comment: @cabrerahector sure.  I want this .json file so I can give it to someone else so when they spin up a Wordpress site, all they need to do is import the .json file and they'll have the website that looks identical to what I currently have on my local environment.

Comment: If they're going to create a copy of your website, and said copy is also a WordPress website, wouldn't it be easier to just give them a [database dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_dump) and a backup of your `wp-content` folder, all in a single .zip file?

Comment: @cabrerahector the reason why I want a `.json` file is because they already have the the exact theme and plugins as I do.  I just want the pages (views) to be on the .json file so that when they import it, they'll have exactly what I have.

Comment: Then the database dump should do. All they'd need to do is import said dump into their database and then update the URLs. But if you really must give them a `.json` file then maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787499/wordpress-rest-api-write-to-json-file/48654786